# Running background process in c++ using pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, background-process

I am developing an API in c++ to be used in iOS and Android development.
Hence, I need to use pthread.

Now I have a function, which sends data to the server after serialization of a queue.

```cpp
//include headers here
 void sendToServer(queue q) {
  /*
  send the whole queue to server after serialization
  pop the queue
  */
}
```

which is called by

```cpp
// headers
void log (data)
{
  while(1)
  {/*
  add data to queue q
  */
  if(num_nodes>=threshold || duration > interval)
  sendToServer(q);
  //apply thread wait condition 
  }
}
```

If i want to make a separate thread for log which runs in the background, can I implement a singleton class with a method get_instance which starts a thread with log

```cpp
class C
{
  private:

    C();
    /*disallow copy constructor and assignment operator*/
    static C* singleton_inst;
    pthread_t t;
    void sendToServer(queue q);

  public:

    void* log(void*);
    static C* get_instance()
    {
      if(singleton_inst==NULL)
      {
        pthread_create(t, NULL, log, NULL);
        singleton_inst= new C();
      }
      return singleton_inst;
    }
}
```

So, next time in my test function, when i do:

`C::get_instance();
 //C::get_instance->signal_thread_to_resume;`

will the second line resume the same thread started in the first line?

Comment: Why can't you use `std::thread`? And if you have C++11 you may want to consider `std::packaged_task`, `std::async` and `std::future`/`std::promise`.

Comment: My peers told me that there have been some cross platform issue with the others. So, I am buying their words. Honestly, I haven't used the others earlier either.

Comment: The `std::` options are standard library functions, so they are generally ... standard. Your colleagues may just not be familiar with C++11.

Comment: And yes, I have C++11

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task etc...

Comment: Hmm. I asked them this too. I would certainly prefer 'std::thread' over 'pthread'. But as C++ is not native for Android, it might pose some additional problems, I guess.

Comment: C++ is just as native for Android as C is.

Comment: Why do you want a singleton? What's wrong with a single global object of a non-copyable type? Singletons are an anti-pattern, [Just Create One](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne)

Comment: Lets assume I want a singleton because well, it's good to have safety. But I am open to suggestions if you can tell me a way to achieve my aim.

Comment: Ultimately, `std::thread` is going to be implemented atop `pthread` on both platforms; `std::thread` is an interface, `pthread` is an implementation. You already have a C++ compiler for both, and as best I can tell both platforms have at least C++0x support since 2012, some C++14 support recently so you have a fairly good chance of having C++11 support in your existing tools. If that's possible, you can leverage these standards and things like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` etc to let you focus on writing the app.

Comment: yes, its true, i can use those libraries too! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use pthread I think this will work, but it is untested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

//include headers here
/*the called function must be void* (void*)  */ 
/* so you have to cast queue*/
 void* sendToServer(void* q) {
  /*
  send the whole queue to server after serialization
  pop the queue
  */
}

pthread_t thread1;

// headers
void log (char* data)
{

  // create the thread
  int th1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, sendToServer, (void*) data);
}

int main() {
  log((char*)"test");
  /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
  /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
  /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */
  pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to link with the pthread libary. Without it, it will not work.
But try to use std::thread.

Comment: I don't think this will run the process in the background. 

Firstly, I think in order for a function to perpetually run in the background, there needs to be an infinite loop inside the function.

Secondly, you created the thread inside log, which means everytime log is called , a new thread with sendToServer will be created. And you have never destroyed the thread. It runs a risk.

Thirdly, what if sendToServer and log are members of different classes?

Comment: I showed you the basic functions of pthread.
In this case the sendToServer function is in a extra thread. If you wan't to get another function in the background you have to do it a similar way.
Of course you can make a loop in the background function, which is for example checking a list of jobs. This list can be a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: @VShreyas I you wan't a detailed answer you have to make detailed question, so show your construct of classes.

Comment: +1. Thanks for showing the basic functionality. I think except the classes part, the question is quite clear. Still, it's not the exact answer I wanted.